# Take picture and save it programmatically in client-sided web application (HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, cordova

**Context:** My client-sided web application should work offline and only depend on HTML and Javascript. The target device is a mobile phone with android, but nice would be a solution which works also in Chrome and Firefox. The pictures should be saved locally on the device and available to save them later on a server.

**Approach:** With getUserMedia i'm able to take a picture and draw it with canvas. Now i'm stucked where i have to save the picture manually. Last approach was to save it in localStorage to access it later.

**Question:** Is there another way to avoid saving the picture in the localStorage? At least i could accept solutions which exclusively targeting mobile browser for android (maybe jquery, phonegap,... ?)

I'd appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IndexedDB or WebSQL with phonegap to store your image data.

However, first try using HTTP cache. Set long expiry headers, Cache-control: public. If you don't need long-term off-line capability, it will "just work".

These links will help you with IndexedDB and WebSQL:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html

http://plugreg.com/plugin/DickvdBrink/cordova-indexeddb

Comment: So my only options to store the pictures in a mobile device, are DBs like IndexedDB and WebSQL or the mobile devices' photo album? To store pictures in devices' filesystem is only allowed by Apps?

Comment: @tvelop: Yes you can save them on device storage i.e sdcard etc using hybrid apps.